# Copy cell content from a column to another column in matlab

Tags: matlab, copy, cell

How should I copy all my cell content in a column to another column in the same cell. e.g.

```
a{1,1}=[1 2];
a{2,1}=[3 4 5];
a = 
[1x2 double]    []
[1x3 double]    []
```

then,I'd like to copy all cell contents of this column to another column say column 2 without copying all rows separately using for. I used

```
a{:,3}=  a{:,2}
The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy the left hand side.
```

it seems that `a{:,2}` is not working as it returns different values in different run. So here `:` doesn't work? 
As an output I'd like to have the same elements as copying cells to my new cell homes. i.e.

```
a{1,2}=[1 2];
a{2,2}=[3 4 5];
```

So, `a` will be

```
a = 
 [1x2 double]  [1x2 double]    
 [1x3 double]  [1x3 double]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use brackets instead if braces in this case.

Try it like this:

```
a = {[0 1];[2 3];[4 5];};
a(:,2) = a(:,1);
```

Comment: Exactly, it works:) Now, if i'd like to check the cells that i'm going to copy to them are empty (column 2 in my example), then copy takes place, how should I proceed?  `if (ismepty(a{:,2}))`... doesnt works and `if (ismepty(a(:,2)))` gives the incorrect answer. should I check it cell by cell?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What cells do you want to check for being empty?

Comment: I mean the cells of column 2 in my example. `if (ismepty(a{:,2}))` or `if (ismepty(a(:,2)))`  doesnt work in this case.

Comment: In this case the problem is that a(:,2) returns a single _cell_ with two non-empty fields, while a{:,2} returns 2 empty _matrices_. In the fist case the cell itself is not empty, even though it contains no data, while in the second case you get an error because, `isempty` takes only one argument. Try: `cellfun(@isempty,a(:,2))`

Comment: Perfect:) Thank you so much, Then `emptyCells = cellfun(@isempty,a(:,2))` gives a column vector if the cells are empty or not. e.g. [1;1] in the case of our example. and we can check e.g. by `if (all(emptyCells == 1))` to see weather all items are 1 or not I think.